# using tawk Tawk_API.setAttributes with reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tawk.to

I have the following App Component :-

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import About from "./pages/About";

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    var Tawk_API = Tawk_API || {},
      Tawk_LoadStart = new Date();
    (function () {
      var s1 = document.createElement("script"),
        s0 = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
      s1.async = true;
      s1.src = "https://embed.tawk.to/5ab8d/default";
      s1.charset = "UTF-8";
      s1.setAttribute("crossorigin", "*");
      s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1, s0);
    })();
    Tawk_API.onLoad = function () {
      console.log("chat loaded");
      Tawk_API.setAttributes(
        {
          name: "Test Name",
          email: "email@email.com",
          hash: "hash value",
        },
        function (error) {}
      );
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="container-fluid rtl">
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I can see that chat widget, but when i am starting a chat , don't get the visitor assigned name.

How can i use the setAttributes in reactjs?

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react';
import {useAuth} from "./auth/context";
import TawkMessengerReact from '@tawk.to/tawk-messenger-react';

function generateName() {...}

const TawkMessenger = () => {
    const tawkMessengerRef = useRef();
    const {user} = useAuth()
    const [isTawkLoaded, setIsTawkLoaded] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        if (tawkMessengerRef.current == null || user == null || !isTawkLoaded) return
        tawkMessengerRef.current.setAttributes({
            reference: user.id,
            name: generateName(user.firstName, user.lastName),
            email: user.email,
            hash: user.tawktoHash,
        }, function (error: unknown) {
            console.log(error)
        })
    }, [user?.tawktoHash, user?.firstName, user?.lastName, user?.email, user?.id, isTawkLoaded])

    return <TawkMessengerReact
        onLoad={() => { setIsTawkLoaded(true) }}
        propertyId="XXXXX"
        widgetId="XXXXX"
        ref={tawkMessengerRef}
    />
}

export default TawkMessenger
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and couldn't figure out why. Unfortunately tawk.to's documentation is a bit poor and ambiguous in some cases.

But after some time I got it to work. I used the ['@tawk.to/tawk-messenger-react'](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tawk.to/tawk-messenger-react) package together with ['crypto-js'](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js).

What **did work** for me was:

1. Using the `setAttributes()` function.
2. Using a hex encoded and stringified output from `CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(message, secret)` as hash.

What **didn't work** for me was:

1. Using the `visitor()` function.
2. Using the direct output from `CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(message, secret)` as hash.

--> **DON'T FORGET TO** enable `Secure Mode` in the tawk.to dashboard for your property – found at `Administration > Overview`.

*Here is a minimum working example of my implementation:*

```js
import React, {
  useRef
} from 'react'

import TawkMessengerReact from '@tawk.to/tawk-messenger-react'
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js'

interface LiveChatProps {
  user: {
    email: string
    name: string
  }
}

const getHexEncodedHash = (message: string, secret: string) => {
  const hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(message, key)

  return CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(hash)
}

const LiveChat = (props: LiveChatProps) => {
  const {
    user
  } = props

  const apiKey = 'e1ba1342e7b0debf218a12146c9a19c6f122cb10' // Example API-key.
  const hash = getHexEncodedHash(user.email, apiKey)

  const tawkMessengerRef = useRef < any > ()

  const onLoad = () => {
    tawkMessengerRef.current.setAttributes({
      name: user.name,
      email: user.email,
      hash: hash
    }, function(error: any) {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }

  return ( <
    TawkMessengerReact propertyId = "63a91def1d362f3a1f32e312" // Example Property ID.
    widgetId = "2gcfikal3" // Example Widget ID.
    onLoad = {
      onLoad
    }
    ref = {
      tawkMessengerRef
    }
    />
  )
}

LiveChat.displayName = 'LiveChat'
export default LiveChat
```

Answer (score 0):

you will get UNAUTHORIZED_API_CALL, you have to use a email and tawk secret for create hash

```
hash:     createHexHash(userState?.data?.email ?? '' ,import.meta.env.VITE_TAWK_API_KEY,),

const hash = createHexHash(userState.data.email, import.meta.env.VITE_TAWK_API_KEY,)
```